# ¿Cómo obtener el índice de una palabra alojada en una sublista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Tengo una la lista `letters`, la cual a su vez tiene sublistas, dichas sublistas contienen entre sus elementos si o si la palabra "BUILD" O "SHOW", o incluso pueden que tengan ambas palabras entre sus elementos.

Lo que quiero lograr es almacenar en `indices` el índice de la primer palabra que se encuentre, por ejemplo `letters[0]` solo contiene la palabra "BUILD" y su índice es `3`, con `letters[1]` contiene las dos palabras, mas sin embargo la que se encuentra de primero es "SHOW", por lo tanto quiero obtener ese índice el cual seria `4`, y por ultimo con `letters[2]` la cual contiene ambas palabras también, mas sin embargo el índice que importa es el de la primer palabra que se encuentre, por lo tanto el índice a devolver es `4`

De manera que al final al imprimir `indices`, el resultado en consola sea `[3, 4, 4]`

Lo que tengo de código es esto:

```
letters = [['a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW']]

def getIndex(list_):
    
    indices = []
    
    for i in range(len(list_)):
        if list_[i] == "BUILD" or list_[i] == "SHOW":
            indices.append(i)
    print(indices)

getIndex(letters)
```

Mas sin embargo la salida en consola que tengo con dicho código solo es `[]`, si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría muy agradecido, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso puede hacerse de la siguiente manera:

*Forma optimizada de hacerlo*

```
indices=[letter.index(element) for letter in letters for element in letter if element=="BUILD" or element=="SHOW"]
print(indices)
```

> El primer for itera en la lista, el segundo en los elementos de la sublista y el if se encarga de hallar los elementos con los nombres indicados, para al final obtener el index de esos elementos con la función de Python index().

*Esto hace lo mismo de una forma menos optimizada pero más fácil de entender*

```
indices=[]
for letter in letters:
    for element in letter:
        if element=="BUILD" or element=="SHOW":
            indices.append(letter.index(element))

print(indices)
```

### Tu código no funciona porque tiene varios errores:

- No iteras en los elementos de la sublista `letters[i]` y en su defecto comparas la entera sublista con el elemento que buscas, en otras palabras estás preguntando si toda la lista es igual a *BUILD* `[1,2,3,"BUILD"]=="BUILD"` en vez de obtener todos los elementos de la lista por separado para luego hacer la comparación.
- Cuando haces el append en la lista no le pasas el índice sino más bien una sublista completa, que en tu caso no llega a guardarse en tu lista `indices` porque `[1,2,3,"BUILD"]=="BUILD"` siempre será falso. Para acceder al índice de un elemento se hace de esta manera `lista.index(elemento)`

> Cualquier otra duda que te haya quedado puedes editar tu pregunta.

Comment: Añadí una explicación del porqué tu código no funcionaba.

Comment: Mucha gracias. solo tuve que agregar un break en la penúltima linea para que hiciera la lista tal y como yo queria, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si obligatoriamente cada sublista tiene alguna de las 2 palabras clave, `SHOW` o `BUILD`, podrías escribirlo como:

```
indices = []
for x in letters:
    if 'SHOW' in x:
        indices.append(x.index('SHOW'))
    else:
        indices.append(x.index('BUILD'))
```

Reescribiendo lo mismo con un operador ternario:

```
indices = []
for x in letters:
    indices.append(x.index('SHOW') if 'SHOW' in x else x.index('BUILD'))
```

Reescribiendo lo anterior en comprensión de listas:

```
indices = [x.index('SHOW') if 'SHOW' in x else x.index('BUILD') for x in letters]
```

Comment: En su ejemplo se ve que hay una lista que contiene tanto SHOW como BUILD y con esta solución solo se obtendría el índice de SHOW. Además de que si en una misma lista hubiera más de una palabra SHOW o BUILD solo se obtendría el índice de la primera coincidencia.